# Jquery Sortable Wrong Position while dragging table rows

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Sortable for dragging table rows

On to the Stop callback function i am doing a ajax call for updating order status

The issue i am facing is that , sometimes i am getting wrong position id while doing drag and drop .

```
$("#languages tbody").sortable(
{
    revert: 'invalid',
    refreshPositions: true,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    helper: 'clone',
    start: function(e, ui)
    {
        $(this).attr('data-previndex', ui.item.index());
    },
    stop: function(e, ui)
    {
        if (!ui.sender)
        {
            var newIndex = ui.item.index() + 1;
            var oldIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-previndex')) + 1;
            var pac_id = ui.item.attr('pacid');
            var inputjson = {
                'pac_id': pac_id,
                'old_position': oldIndex,
                'new_position': newIndex
            };
            var reqested_data = JSON.stringify(inputjson);
            console.log('JSON Request' + reqested_data);
            $(this).removeAttr('data-previndex');
            $.ajax(
            {
                // ajax call here 
            });
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PP2ba/23/

Could you please let me know how to fix this .

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "sometimes"? Do you know what cause this behavior?

Comment: sometimes means reproducible when doing drag and drop very quickly .

Comment: I might have a similar problem: see this gif (http://gph.is/2p3dP4u). Did you find a fix yet?